# gulp-handlebars compliles template with a lot of extra code

Tags: javascript, gulp, handlebars.js

i am using handlebars for templating, and gulp fro complyling the template to js. For the gulp task I am using [gulp-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-handlebars). All works well and good, but the end result file, dose have a lot of odd expressions that replace every variable that I have:

Template:

```
<a ... href="{{imageData}}" ....
```

compiled result:

```
+ alias4(((helper = (helper = helpers.id || (depth0 != null ? depth0.id : depth0)) != ? helper : alias2),(typeof helper === alias3 ? helper.call(alias1,{"name":"id","hash":{},"data":data}) : helper)))
```

This is something that i do not understand why I need, since it makes the size of my templates almost double.

is there any way of replacing this with just the variable reference?

The code that I use for the compilation is this:

```
 gulp.src(TEMPLATE_FOLDER + '/*.hbs')
    .pipe(handlebars())
    .pipe(wrap('Handlebars.template(<%= contents %>)'))
    .pipe(declare({
        namespace: 'app.templates',
        noRedeclare: true,
    }))
    .pipe(concat('T_Compiled.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(TEMPLATE_FOLDER));
```